# Динамический выбор хранилища из UI .net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .netcore2.0

Есть 2 Бд 1 реляцаонная PostgreSql другая документо-ориентированая MongoDb. 
И есть реализация Интерфейсов для работы с postgreSql и MongoDb.

Хочу подключать динамически реализацию для mongoDb или PostgreSql в зависимости от выбранного хранилища, которое можно выбрать из UI.

Проблема заключается в том что ресурсы не освобождаются ,то ли все кешируется... И даже если делать перегрузку конструктора, все равно все остается по умолчанию.. . Может быть сам конвеер вообще нельзя трогать ? в ASP.NET MVC немного все подругому , и все сделать можно было без проблем.. А тут .net core для меня открытие , и не могу сдвинутся никак.. Может кто сталкивался , и уже нашел другой подход. Реализация на asp.net mvc 5 + web-api2 + angular 2 https://github.com/RomanBarashcov/LibraryApp

Выбор хранилища получается только вручную , через остановку приложения и присвоение переменной conString  = "DefaultConnection"

класс Startup:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        conString = "MongoDb";
    }

    public Startup(IConfiguration _configuration, string _conString, IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Dispose();
        conString = _conString;
        Configuration = _configuration;
        ConfigureServices(new ServiceCollection());
        Configure(app, env);
    }

    private Container container = new Container();
    public string conString { get; set;}
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public IServiceCollection serviceCollection { get; set; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        string connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<LibraryPostgreSqlContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connection, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("LibraryAppCore.WebUI")));

        services.AddMvc(options =>
        {
            options.RespectBrowserAcceptHeader = true;
        });

        IServiceCollectionExtension.Configuration = Configuration;

        IntegrateSimpleInjector(services);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        IServiceCollectionExtension.app = app;
        IServiceCollectionExtension.env = env;

        InitializeContainer(app);


        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });


            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });

        });

    }

    private void IntegrateSimpleInjector(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new AsyncScopedLifestyle();

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

        services.AddSingleton<IControllerActivator>(
            new SimpleInjectorControllerActivator(container));
        services.AddSingleton<IViewComponentActivator>(
            new SimpleInjectorViewComponentActivator(container));

        services.EnableSimpleInjectorCrossWiring(container);
        services.UseSimpleInjectorAspNetRequestScoping(container);
    }

    private void InitializeContainer(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Add application presentation components:
        container.RegisterMvcControllers(app);
        container.RegisterMvcViewComponents(app);

        // Add application services. For instance:
        if(conString == "DefaultConnection")
        {
            container.Register<IAuthorRepository, AuthorPostgreSqlConcrete>();
            container.Register<IBookRepository, BookPostgreSqlConcrete>();
            container.Register<IConvertDataHelper<AuthorPostgreSql, Author>, AuthorPostgreSqlConvert>();
            container.Register<IConvertDataHelper<BookPostgreSql, Book>, BookPostgreSqlConvert>();
        }
        else
        {
            container.Register<IAuthorRepository, AuthorMongoDbConcrete>();
            container.Register<IBookRepository, BookMongoDbConcrete>();
            container.Register<IConvertDataHelper<AuthorMongoDb, Author>, AuthorMongoDbConvert>();
            container.Register<IConvertDataHelper<BookMongoDb, Book>, BookMongoDbConvert>();
        }

        container.Register<IDataRequired<Author>, AuthorDataRequired>();
        container.Register<IDataRequired<Book>, BookDataRequired>();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        container.Dispose();
        container = new Container();
    }
}
```

Comment: Исходя из вашего кода, к моменту запуска приложения ваша строка соединения уже выбрана, и вы уже никак не можете на это повлиять. Мне кажется, вам нужен другой подход к решению задачи

Comment: Я потом перегружаю конструктор , и передаю новое значение в conString и формирую конфигурацию заново , вызывая методы , которые вызывает ядро .asp.net core  
public Startup(IConfiguration _configuration, string _conString, IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Dispose();
        conString = _conString;
        Configuration = _configuration;
        ConfigureServices(new ServiceCollection());
        Configure(app, env);
    }

Comment: Но контейнер вы при этом пересоздаете или пытаетесь существуюший перенастроить?

Comment: пытаюсь существующий перенастроить, Может что-то не так делаю?

Comment: Значит смотрите в дебаге верно ли он перенастраивается. Судя по тому, что используется старый контекст, контейнер остается настроен по старому

Comment: буду разбиратся , спасибо . Просто даже не могу найти реализацию проекта для 2-х бд для .net core

Comment: Как по мне - так это должно быть прописано в конфиг файле, а не в какой то переменной. Чтобы была возможность сохранить выбор юзера, рестартануть, и считать этот выбор на старте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 services.AddTransient<IAuthorRepository>(provider =>
        {
            if (ConnectionDB.ConnectionString == "DefaultConnection")
            {
                services.AddTransient<IConvertDataHelper<AuthorPostgreSql, Author>, AuthorPostgreSqlConvert>();
                return new AuthorPostgreSqlConcrete(new LibraryPostgreSqlContext(optionsBuilder.Options), new AuthorPostgreSqlConvert(), new AuthorDataRequired());
            }
            else
            {
                services.AddTransient<IConvertDataHelper<AuthorMongoDb, Author>, AuthorMongoDbConvert>();
                return new AuthorMongoDbConcrete(new LibraryMongoDbContext(), new AuthorMongoDbConvert(), new AuthorDataRequired());
            }

        });
```